# Catastrophic backtracking searching for numbers in brackets

Tags: regex, backtracking

With this regex: `\((\W*\d*\W*)*\)` I am looking for numbers inside brackets. These numbers can be surrounded by any symbols but not characters and this pattern can appear a lot of times inside brackets, I mean I need to match everything here:

- (8)
- (8,)
- (  8'' )
- (8, 9, 8 ,9)
- (18, 9', 89;)
- (' 7; 27; 37.38; 48 ; 55)

but NOT:

- (8j)
- (a888)
- (1, 2; 12.13; 25.26; 35.36; 43.45; 52.56; 59,6o)

and exactly the last example gives me a Catastrophic backtracking error. How can I avoid this error? I really don't understand how to do it...

Comment: If you're always expecting at least one digit then you shouldn't use the `*` quantifier after `\d` as well as after the capture group. Use `+` instead.

Comment: Can you use the following maybe [`(?:\(|\G(?!^))[^a-z\n\)]*?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^a-z\n\)]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/rN6So2/1/)

Comment: @silkfire `(\W*\d+\W*)+` still has catastrophic backtracking because of the two adjacent `\W*` in a group repetition (fix that by using `(\W*\d+)+\W*` instead), and by `\W*` possibly matching nothing so adjacent digits might be repetitions of the outer group (fix that by using `(\W*\d)+\W*` or `\W*\d+(\W+\d+)*\W*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your regex to `\([\W\d]*\)` which will match and not match your examples.

See https://regex101.com/r/DNmuEb/1/

Comment: I think this is the best and cleaner solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The catastrophic backtracking for `\((\W*\d*\W*)*\)` is due to the nested optional quantifiers, and everything is optional.

Note that `\W` can also match `(` and `)`

You can match any whitespace char except for chars A-Z a-z or parenthesis and assert at least a single digits between parenthesis if you need to match everything

```
\((?=[^()\d]*\d)[^A-Za-z()]+\)
```

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?=[^()\d]*\d)` Assert at least a digit between the parenthesis
- `[^A-Za-z()]+` Match 1+ times any char except chars A-Z a-z ( ) and add more if you want to extend it
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e5nRWS/1)